# Listening to XMLHttpRequest.upload.onprogress cost 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' while uploading an image through formData?

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, form-data

Today I stucked into a weird issue while I'm trying to upload an image to my server through AJAX2 `formData`, however an 'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' shown up.

Everything is ok on my server side because the upload service has been used for a while.

After debug line by line, again and again (T__T), I found out it is the `xml.upload.onprogress` that make this error happened.

```
// This works without listening to the progress event

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var form = new FormData();
form.append('img', myFile, myFilesName);

// Both of them will make this error happen!
// xhr.upload.onprogress = function() {}; 
// xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(){}); 

xhr.open('POST','my_server_side_url');
xhr.send(form);
```

However when I add the `progress` event listener to the `xhr`, even I do nothing in the callback, the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error show up.

Isn't it weird? Anyone knows why this happening?

Thx!!